# Java 9, Hibernate and java.sql/javax.transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jdbc, java-9

I've tried to "upgrade" a project using Hibernate to Java 9, but I am having problems getting the module to function properly.

The relevant part of my `module-info.java` looks like this:

```
module test {

    ...

    requires java.base;
    requires hibernate.core;
    requires javax.transaction;
    requires java.sql;

}
```

and the relevant dependencies in my POM are

- `org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec`, 2.0.0.Alpha1
- `org.hibernate:hibernate-core`, 5.2.12.Final
- `javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api`, 1.2

The problem is, if I run the program, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `javax.transaction.SystemException`. I looked into this, and quite obviously, [my module is missing a `requires` on `javax.transaction`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515230/hibernate-java-9-and-systemexception).

So I add a module dependency on `javax.transaction-api`. I then go on and attempt to run the program again - now I'm missing `java.sql.SQLException`.

Here is what I am having a problem with: if I [add a dependency on the module `java.sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852809/java-9-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-java-sql-sqlexception-in-spring-boot-a), which contains this class, I end up with a conflict:

> module reads package `javax.transaction.xa` from both `java.sql` and `javax.transaction.api`

`java.sql` and `javax.transaction.api` contain different packages, and have one in common (`javax.transaction.xa`), **but I require all of them**.

How do I deal with this? Is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: Seems similar to a [linked comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852809/java-9-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-java-sql-sqlexception-in-spring-boot-a#comment82696084_47852809) and a relevant [reply from Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852809/java-9-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-java-sql-sqlexception-in-spring-boot-a#comment82698260_47852809)

Comment: There's a MR of JSR 907 in progress (https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=907) to fix this. Once that is fixed then I would expect a new version of the JTA API artifact to be published with the right module name and also exporting only javax.transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use version 1.3 instead of 1.2 of `javax.transaction-api`, in this version `javax.transaction.xa` has been removed.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```